# Why does scanner.next() cause JUnit test to Hang

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have a JUnit Test in Eclipse (I tried this with Junit 3 and JUnit 4) that checks a Method that parses a file But For some reason unknown to me It freezes or hangs when I use this:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine() && scanner !=null){
   if(scanner.hasNext()){ do something }
}
```

but When I use the following it works fine:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine() && scanner !=null && scanner.hasNext() ){
   do something 
}
```

The code in "do something" does noting special except assign scanner.next() to variables, which actually output fine using the `System.out.print()` in both cases. Are these Not doing the Same Thing? and is this a reasonable Error (if so Please explain why) or is it a silly bug?

Comment: Why are you checking for `null` _after_ dereferencing `scanner` - that seems like a bug. Any why do you need to check `hasNextLine()` _and_ `hasNext()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check for null before dereferencing a reference.
Change

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine() && scanner !=null){
   if(scanner.hasNext()){ do something }
}
```

to this:

```
while(scanner !=null && scanner.hasNextLine()){
   if(scanner.hasNext()){ do something }
}
```

As written in your example code, you will find null scanner instances, but the (scanner != null) will never matter.  Instead, you will find null scanners via a NullPointerException.

Next, you mention in your question that you "assign scanner.next() to variables".
Show some code.  You must make exactly one `hasNextLine` call for each `nextLine` call and you must make exactly one `hasNext` call for each `next` call.  It appears that you might be doing something like this:

```
while (blam.hasNext())
{
    blah = blam.next();
    hoot = blam.next();
}
```

this is totally wrong.  the second next call will cause issues.